# Lightbox showing image 2 on click instead of image 1

Tags: javascript, lightbox2

On my 'work' page, when I click on the button to view one of the galleries, the 2nd image shows up before the 1st image. I have to click back to image 1 to view it rather than click next to the 2nd image.

Comment: sounds like a problem with line 37

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to show us the problem code before we can be of much help.

Comment: Hi. OK, sorry, I'm very new to this. My apologies. So, the thing is, I don't know where the problem is. The facts are this (sorry for not elaborating more before): I have simply loaded the Lightbox2 js and css and had to do nothing to really make this work. I included the

Comment: Sorry bout that too. Hit enter and it sent the message. So I included the code for the images according to what is required from the Lightbox website as follows: <a href="../Images/FolioImages/ABFloor/abfloorslide/ABFloorBC.png" data-lightbox="AB Floor" data-title="AB Floor"><img src="../Images/FolioImages/ABFloor/ABFloorLogosmall.png" alt="AB Floor Gallery button" width="150" height="150" class="imggal" id="abfloor"/></a>

Comment: That's all I had to do to get the gallery to work. And it does, fine. Except for the fact that image 2 loads instead of image 1. I hope this all makes sense.

Comment: Trying this again. This is the code:   <a href="../Images/FolioImages/ABFloor/abfloorslide/ABFloorBC.png" data-lightbox="AB Floor" data-title="AB Floor"><a href="../Images/FolioImages/ABFloor/abfloorslide/ABFloorLogo.png" data-lightbox="AB Floor" data-title="AB Floor"><img src="../Images/FolioImages/ABFloor/ABFloorLogosmall.png" alt="AB Floor Gallery button" width="150" height="150" class="imggal" id="abfloor"/></a>